# Jquery hierarchical/tree view plugin

Tags: jquery

I am new to Jquery and was wondering if it is possible to the following with one of the screens in my application:

```
If I have 3 draggable/droppable elements  - A, B and C arranged on screen:
                           A



                B                      C
If I drag element B onto Element A, I would like to draw a link between elements 
A and B:

                          A
                          |
                          |
                  ________|
                 |
                B                     C

If I drag element C onto Element A, I would like to draw a link between elements A
and C as follows:


                         A
                         |
                         |
                 ________|__________                                    
                |                   |
                B                   C
```

Note: A, B and C will be icons/images in the real application

So to me this seems like a tree or hierarchical view to me. Does anybody know if there are any plugins that could do something like this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this link: http://www.graphdracula.net

It does not much, but may be it would be a good starting point that you can enhance.

Also don't miss the "Similar Projects" section on the right of that page - I found few useful plugins for myself from there.

Comment: Thanks, these projects look promising: [The JIT](http://thejit.org/demos/) [JS-Graph-IT](http://js-graph-it.sourceforge.net/) [JSPlumb](http://code.google.com/p/jsplumb/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether this is an overkill in your case, but you could try [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/).
it supports jQuery's draggable / droppable.